# Jquery excel export is not working in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, excel

I want to download my HTML table as Excel. For that I used the given code

```
$('#export').click(function (e) {
   var dt = new Date();
   var day = dt.getDate();
   var month = dt.getMonth() + 1;
   var year = dt.getFullYear();
   var hour = dt.getHours();
   var mins = dt.getMinutes();
   var postfix = day + "." + month + "." + year + "_" + hour + "." + mins;
   var a = document.createElement('a');
   var data_type = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel';
   var table_div = document.getElementById('reportDiv');
   var table_html = table_div.outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');
   a.href = data_type + ', ' + table_html;
   a.download = 'UserMatrix' + postfix + '.xls';
   a.click();
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

It's working in Chrome and Firefox but not working in Internet Explorer 9.

Comment: Have you tried compatibility mode in IE?? it tends to fix a lot of issues. Let me know if it works!

Comment: @racecarjonathan - no change. the same issue

Comment: what version IE are you running?

Comment: its Internet explorer 9

Comment: is there a reason you are on 9 and not 11? just curious?

Comment: IE doesn't support the anchor tag's `Download` attribute http://caniuse.com/#feat=download

Comment: @Brett - is there any method for downloading?

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to use an alternate solution for IE9 as it doesn't support the HTML `download` attribute for the anchor tag.

Here's a popular Javascript option:
https://github.com/dcneiner/Downloadify

It uses Flash, though, which IE 9 would support.